# How to calculate the size of the page table from this data?

Tags: cache, paging

A computer uses 46–bit virtual address, 32–bit physical address, and a three–level page table organization.

The page table base register stores the base address of the first–level table, which occupies exactly one page.

- Each entry of the first level page table stores the base address of a page of the second–level table.
- Each entry of the second level page table  stores the base address of a page of the third–level table.
- Each entry of the third level page table stores a page table entry (PTE). The PTE is 32 bits in size.

The processor used in the computer has a 1 MB 16 way set associative virtually indexed physically tagged cache. The cache block size is 64 bytes.

Comment: This is obviously a [homework question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) - what does your textbook say? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I came across this question in an exam actually, what i cannot figure out is how to calculate the page tablesize from this data, it would be helpful to provide some references to solve this question. All examples in the text book already provide the size of the page table, so i can't seem to find out how to find out the page table size from this data

Answer (score 2):

toatl 46bits,
physial 32bits,

left =(46-32)=14bits,

Now, first–level table, which occupies exactly one page. whis require at least 1bit. 
So 14bits - 1bit = 13bits of address line left. Rest is `miss`load cache.

:. total page size is 2^13 Bytes = 2^3KiB=8KiB

Comment: Can you please explain the "Now, first–level table, which occupies exactly one page. whis require at least 1bit." part